# sql statement to regnerate auto increment field from start to end again

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have one MYSQL table.

In that table there is one column name SRNO is its primary key and auto increment also.

I have around 25000 records in that table but some records between the table is deleted.

For example record no 10 is deleted etc.

I want a SQL script to run mysql to regenerate all auto increment field so that it start from 1 again and end at last record to avoid that missing records.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Comment: Alter table > drop column > add new column again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally not considered a good idea, as you can seriously mess with referential integrity this way.  If this is an aesthetics thing, I'd recommend leaving it as-is.  That being said, here's what you do:

- create a new table with the same schema as the old one, and set your auto-increment to 1.
- insert all records from the old table into the new one, except for the auto-increment column.
- rename the original table to something else
- rename the new table to the original name

this will effectively "reseed" your table.